# Why does connecting colorramp Alpha to Material Output Displacement cause object to turn magenta in Render Preview mode?

Tags: texturing

I just started learning Blender. According to the lesson, I began to try to adjust the materials for the default cube. When applying such nodes as noise texture and colorramp, I connected from the alpha output to the Material Output's Displacement input. I found out that,
the cube changed color to magenta, and the tutorial shows how to apply a noise texture, i.e. change it. Please tell me what could be the matter, why is this happening to me?[image: Screenshot showing material and magenta monkey]

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to direct the title of the question to the topic? The title "Help me please!" does not help anyone to see what this is about, so it is unlikely that anyone will help you. Thank you!

Comment: Displacement is essentially a _Vertex Shader_ and is used with B&W images through a _Displacement Node_ in order to provide a "heightmap" so to speak for the displacement of vertices. You should not have your alpha (or any alpha for that matter) connected to displacement.  Also - magenta is blender's color for "cannot find texture", so that's a clue somethings amiss.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting the tutorial again and take your time to find out what you did wrong before.

Try disconnecting the *Alpha* value from *Displacement* to see if the gradient is visible.

Second, the displacement should be only visible in Cycles Render, so try to switch to *Rendered View*.

[image]